# SVN Hook stopped working - SVN update not executing

Tags: svn, batch-file, cmd, visualsvn-server, post-commit-hook

I have an SVN repository I set up about a month ago and after some struggles got a post-commit hook working to update a working copy of my web site on the development server. It was working fine for several days and then, yesterday, all of the sudden, it stopped.

I am running VisualSVN Server from a server on my network. As far as I know, nothing has changed on the web server or the server hosting the VisualSVN server. The VisualSVN server doesn't show any events in the event viewer for the past several days, so I can't see if there is an error and I can't find any log files specific to SVN. When I run 'svn log' it doesn't show anything but the commits. I'm not sure if it would show an error if there was one.

Here is a scrubbed copy of the script that is running:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

svnlook dirs-changed %1 -r %2 | findstr /b /i "trunk" 

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    FOR /F "tokens=2" %%a IN ('svnlook changed %1 -r %2') DO (
    SET NEWA=%%a 
    SET "NEWB=!NEWA:trunk/=!"
    svn update \\<server-name>\<share>\dev\<working-copy-directory>\!NEWB! --username <svnuser> --password <svnpass>) 
)

endlocal
```

i have also checked for any locks on the server and found none and run a cleanup of the working copy on my DEV server as well, all to no avail. I also attempted an update from another workstation, just to see if it could be my local machine and it still didn't run properly. Lastly, I have also attempted to run the script from the command line and it runs and updates the working copy like it should. It actually seems as if the server just isn't running it.

Any help debugging this issue is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: After finding some debugging strategies I was able to confirm that the hook is, indeed, running by including a command as follows:

```
echo hook ran at %date% %time% >> debug.txt
```

This logged the commit, as would be expected. I also included similar debug code to make sure that the hook was catching the correct trunk/branch, which it was and I also had it log the directory before the update so I new it was going to run that command. All of which it did. Then, in an attempt to log the server response, I changed the update code to the following:

```
svn update \\<server-name>\<share>\dev\<working-copy-directory>\!NEWB! --username <svnuser> --password <svnpass> >> debug.txt)
```

This returns nothing at all. I am at a complete loss on this.

UPDATE 2: I didn't get this earlier when I was testing this problem, but now when I run the command on it's own...

```
svn update \\<server>\<share>\dev\<working-copy>\ScriptContent\test.cfm --username <svnuser> --password
```

It returns "svn: E020024: Error resolving case of " and spits out the path I just gave it.

I did try to google some sources of this problem, but the only thing I found suggests switching the backslashes with slashes, but it returns the exact same error, but with the slashes switched back to backslashes.

UPDATE 3: In an effort to check if the error was related to the server running as the Network Service and attempting to access the working copy via the UNC path, I attempted changing the service to running in my name and mapping the network drive and using this mapped drive in the script. This test gave me no errors but did not execute the update.

Also, the more that I think about it, the error that I was getting from the command line in UPDATE 2 above is probably not what is happening when the script runs, as the commit screen on the client side (run by TortoiseSVN) would show me the error. It does not show any errors.

So, this is what I know.

1. The script worked fine for several days
2. The script suddenly stopped working some time over the weekend
3. No changes were made to the server hosting the working copy or the server running the repository
4. The hook is not generating any errors (as these would display in the TortoiseSVN commit screen).
5. The svn update command is not executing.

I am at a complete loss.

Comment: do you see any errors on client-side?

Comment: No, nothing. I suspect that the hook isn't even running - but that is even more confounding, seeing that the repository itself is updating fine.

Comment: Actually, I can confirm now that the script is running - updating post above

Comment: Try to log the problematic line before executing it by `echo svn update \\<server-n ... >> debug.txt`. Does your password,servername,share or working-copy-directory contains problematic characters, like one of `)&,;:<>|` ?

Comment: I will try to log that and post it here. There are no special characters in any of those fields

Comment: When I log it, it does look a bit odd as the slashes are off in the path: svn update \\Mserver>\<share>\dev\<working-copy>\ScriptContent/test.cfm  --username <svnuser> --password <svnpass>

Comment: Also, I didn't think about it, but the <share> identified does have a $ symbol in it. Still not sure why any of these things would have worked before and then stopped working all of the sudden.

Comment: More added above under UPDATE 2

Comment: I found the solution. Answer posted below

Answer (score 1):

After several days of fighting with this I finally found a solution. VisualSVN Server, by default, runs on the Network Service user account. In order to fix the problem, I followed these steps.

1. Set up user account on the repository server as a member of VisualSVN Server Admins group
2. Assigned the VisualSVN Server service to run under this account
3. Set up user account on the web server as a member of the Administrators group, with the same name and password as the account on the repository server
4. Restarted the VisualSVN Server service

After that it worked. The hook is running SVN update on the files, exactly as expected and updating the web server working copy with the committed changes. I hope this is a help to someone else out there as well, as it took quite a lot of work to figure this out.

Comment: What you did it pretty unsecure! DON'T add service accounts to Administrator groups.

As far as I see now, the root cause was insufficient access to the working copy on a share.

Comment: commented in your answer above

Answer (score 0):

What you did it pretty unsecure! DON'T add service accounts to Administrator groups.

As far as I see now, **the root cause was insufficient access to the working copy on a share**.

You must provide VisualSVN Server's service account with access to the share. (NTFS and Share permissions). By default, VisualSVN Server's service runs under "Network Service" account. This account is identified as COMPUTER account on the network. So you must provide the COMPUTER account with access to the share where your working copy is located. If you still intend to run the server under dedicated account: the article http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00024/ is MUST-READ!

Comment: We tried that and it wouldn't work. We tried giving full access to the share to the account and it wouldn't update. The only way it would update was by assigning admin rights.